# How to read QR code from the pepper robot?

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner, pepper

I am working on QR code scanning features of the pepper robot but I could not find a way to scan the QR code. I had tried using ALBarcodeReader and also subscribe to ALMemory Event "BarcodeReader/BarcodeDetected". Nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please add the code that you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

In NAOqi 2.5, ALBarcodeReader works for reading QR Codes; see the sample code here:

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/vision/albarcodereader-tuto.html

Make sure you call

```
 ALBarcodeReader.subscribe("some-subscriber-id")
```

... before you get the ALMemory key.